# On Android, how are Wi-Fi and 3G Internet traffic saved to memory, and when refreshed or cleared by the system?

Tags: android, wifi, traffic

I need to know about Wi-Fi and 3G Internet traffic. I found this traffic data is saved to `/statistics/rx_bytes`, `/statistics/tx_bytes`, `/sys/class/net/` paths.
Question: If I get data from these paths, what does this data mean? When did this data start being gathered: from Wi-Fi activation or from phone switch-on?
And when does the system clear or refresh this Wi-Fi traffic data? (My app needs to save daily traffic)

Comment: can you solve your question? are you give some example to using the /statistics/rx_bytes, /statistics/tx_bytes, /sys/class/net/ to read the traffic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found these traffics data are saved on "/statistics/rx_bytes", "/statistics/tx_bytes", "/sys/class/net/" paths.

Do not use these, as they may not exist on all devices. Use [`TrafficStats`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html), please.

> If i get data from these paths, what does it mean these data.

Please read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) for [`TrafficStats`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html).

> When this data started gathering: from WiFi activated or from phone switched on?

That is undocumented and therefore may vary.

> And when system clears or refreshes this wifi traffic data?

That too is undocumented and therefore may vary.

Comment: i used these paths because i didn't know how to get WiFi and 3G traffics separately by using TrafficStats, thanks for your advice and information